# Symfony2 combining all my resources even if I tell it to NOT

Tags: php, symfony

Well, in our project, that was managed by some evil devops with a limited knowledge of even 2+2, some things are just weird...

Like for example, our project is combining all .css and .js files into one, even in dev mode, EVEN if we tell it to not... Maybe I am missing something...

```
assetic:
    debug: "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    assets:
        forms_js:
            inputs:
                - @AppBundle/Resources/public/js/foo.js
                - @AppBundle/Resources/public/js/bar.js

        forms_css:
            inputs:
                - @AppBundle/Resources/public/css/foo.css
                - @AppBundle/Resources/public/css/bar.css
```

In our `config.dev` we have `use_controller: true`

And our twig has

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets '@forms_css' %}
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" media="all"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@forms_js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

So there's no COMBINE, no filter used, nothing, but Symfony keeps creating files like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/app_dev.php/css/b940fcc_part_1.css" media="all"/>

<script src="/app_dev.php/js/f9411fd_part_1.js"></script>
```

This doesn't bother me on PROD, because of reasons, but when we are on DEVELOPMENT, we need to debug our files and search for things, this is impossible when our files are combined into an oneliner file from hell...

As far as I remember, while in dev, symfony2 creates your resources with their names

For example

`/app_dev.php/js/fasguig2b3_foo_1.js` and `/app_dev.php/js/fasguig2b3_foo_2.js` but never combined...

What am I missing?

PS: caches and stuff cleared all the time.

Maybe there isn't a problem actually, it is just the way Symfony2 handles assets inside yaml?

because if you put them inside `{% javascripts 'something.js' 'other.js' %}` it doesn't combine them, only if you use `{% '@my_js' %}` referencing yaml

Comment: Are you sure there are no third-party compression libraries installed?

Comment: Yep, no third-party things installed. u_u

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have separated files you should use assets in Twig, not in YAML mapping, otherwise it will merge all even if you tell it not to.